# Virtual memory layout of 32bit process

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, virtual-memory

I would like to have better understanding on virtual address space for 32bit windows c++ application. I found picture representing it somewhere on Internet([link](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2009/07/19/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-1-stack-based-overflows/)). Is it more or less correct?
I created some sample.exe application that depends on static library and DLL and prints addresses of variables and functions(all are in table). I see couple differences between my results and this picture: 
1.There is fixed 0x00400000 address where Program image section should start. However I see that my variable on heap has address of 0041A168. Shouldn't they be smaller then 0x00400000 or higer then all Program image addresses?
2. I print address of std::abs(double) and it is in Program image section. Does it mean it is in some static library?
3. I print address of getchar and fopen. Does it mean they are in DLL library?

[image]

Comment: `0x00400000` is no longer correct. Modern windows randomizes the layout in an attempt to make it more difficult to implement malware. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows

Comment: The specific numbers in that diagram are merely for illustration. The actual numbers may vary.

Comment: That image is wildly misleading.  If you found 0041A168 back then don't assume it is stored on the heap, static data is much more likely.  Consider using the SysInternals' VMMap utility, it gives you accurate info that is relevant to your program.  The "Windows Internals" book tells you everything you'd ever want to know about memory.

Comment: i created that variable with new operator so how can it not be stored on the heap?

Comment: @user7242858 If you created it on the heap, then it's on the heap. But if you just stumbled across the number `0041A168`, there's no guarantee that that number is always an address in the heap. (Also, there's no requirement that the heap be placed in a particular location, or grow in a particular direction, or even occupy contiguous memory. That diagram is very simplified from reality.)

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram is a pedagogical tool that does not reflect a real world implementation. The only thing you can count on is that some range of addresses will be dedicated to the user space and another range will be dedicates to the system space.

You can somewhat count on a low range of pages being marked with no access. However, this can usually be overridden by the user.